# How can used cppcheck execute in the project in console?, maybe search reference in makefile?

Tags: c, parameters, makefile, command, cppcheck

I have a project that be make all in terminal, in C and i am using ccpcheck file by file but i would like to used for check all files how a um project . I try used command with parameters :
cppcheck --enable=all  *.c  ,in the folder but show me less errors than check file by file.

There are better method for to do this ?
if you can help me

Comment: all this in environment Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
cppcheck --enable=all .
```

that scans all source files in current folder and in all subfolders